# (TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float) using 'i' for list index

Tags: python

The goal of this is to print anything below the weight limit. I am receiving 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float' because i am trying to use 'i' as the list index i assume.

```
weights = [.0005, 300000, 3.52, .05, 13]
weightLimit = 1
i = 0

for i in weights:
    while i <= (weightLimit):
        print(animals[i])
        i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `enumerate`. It creates an iterable containing the index and the value at each iteration. Also, because it's a `for` loop, you don't need to initialise and increment the loop variable. Finally, you may use a `if` statement inside the `for`, not a `while`.

```
weights = [.0005, 300000, 3.52, .05, 13]
weightLimit = 1

for ind, weight in enumerate(weights):
    if weight <= (weightLimit):
        print(animals[ind])
```

Based on what I'm assuming that you want to do, you could also use a list comprehension in one line :

```
print([animal for animal, weight in zip(animals, weights) if weight <= weightLimit])
```

Note that I did not do it exactly as the bigger version. Here I'm iterating on `zip(animals, weights)` which is an iterator that generates tuples of form `(animals[i], weight[i])`.